# Reset as output... So how to unlock Atmega8?

Tags: atmega

I by accident set port C as output, and now I can't load new program to cpu, but processor is detected (I using mkAVR Calculator(programming process is "done" but in verification process I get error)). So how I can reverse my mistake ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the datasheet:

> When programming the RSTDISBL Fuse Parallel Programming has to be used to change
>   fuses or perform further programming

So, use a parallel programmer.